# Laravel Queue curl_multi_wait error while listening to SQS

Tags: php, laravel, curl, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue

I configured Laravel to use queue on SQS (AWS Simple Queue Service).

As I see now inside AWS monitoring console: SQS queue is working fine and receiving messages from Laravel.

The last thing I need to do is to run `php artisan queue:listen` but I got this kind of error

```
/usr/local/php/cgi/7.3/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/php/cgi/7.3/lib/ph
p/20180731/curl.so: undefined symbol: curl_multi_wait
```

Comment: what does it print(version key) when you execute `curl_version()` on tinker?

Comment: "version_number" => 464384, "version" => "7.22.0"

Comment: according to here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_wait.html - that method is added on `This function was added in libcurl 7.28.0.`